# Google Developer Console not showing usage for YouTube Data API v3

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

As instructed [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/support) I'm posting this on stackoverflow, in regards to YouTubePlayerFragment in my Android app.

I set up my Android YouTube Data API v3 key in the Google Developer Console (GDC) and the in-app player has been working fine in my production app for over a month. Today my player stopped loading and playing videos. It initializes fine and then onStopped is called. I have a feeling I have hit the quota since there was a popularity spike today. However, going to the YouTube Data API v3 in GDC and going to "usage" shows nothing. No requests, ever. If I select "manage all projects" I see 0 requests and 22 errors for the project with the YouTube API enabled.

Can anyone provide some insights? I can't find any way of contacting Google about this.

**EDIT:** I don't think it has to do with the quota anymore (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203065/youtubeplayerfragment-calling-onstopped-after-oninitializationsuccess)). It seems to have something to do with ads. **However, the question remains, why do I see no usage? Is playing of videos not a quotable use?**

Comment: Can you provide us your error logs? for the meantime, you may look try to check Youtube Data API errors here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors. For more informatioregarding Quota usage, here's the link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

Comment: There are no errors! Please see updated question. @d.datul1990

Comment: As you mentioned, you have 22 errors for the project with the Youtube API

Comment: @d.datul1990 Sorry I thought you meant from my app. Where might I find what the errors are? All I see is the number of errors on the "Manage all projects" page, and it's up to 164 errors now.